# Change a bullet point color within a before selector with CSS

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I am trying to change the color of a bullet point. You'll better understand my request with the image below.

[image: click here to see the image]

So far, I successfully made it, but I can't find a way to change the bullet point to red.

Here's my CSS :

```css
h3#one {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

h3#one::before {
    content: '1.';
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-right: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<h3 id="one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h3>
```

Is there a way to make it with CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can achieve this with a pseudo class but you could do something like this.

```css
h3 {
  display:block;
}

h3 .red {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-right: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h3>1<span class="red">.</span></h3>
<h3> Test</h3>
```

Comment: Thanks ! This method is the simplest one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the dot red you can do it with a span like this: `<h3>Your text<span style="color: red">.</span></h3>`

Answer (score 0):

You can. You just shouldn't be doing it with the '1' in the pseudo-class too. Instead, put the value inside the tag and use the `::before` only to style the dot.

```css
h3 {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;}

h3::before {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
margin-left: 10px;
color: red;
content: '.';
font-size: 40px;
margin-right: 24px;
margin-bottom: 8px;}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<h3>1</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

If you don't want this approach, I suggest using the `span` tag to do the trick.

```
<h3>1<span style="color: red">.</span></h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a gradient background and [`background-clip: text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip).

```css
h3 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

h3::before {
    counter-reset: num var(--num);
    content: counter(num) '.';
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-right: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    align-self: start;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, red, red), linear-gradient(90deg, black, black);
    background-size: 0.25em, auto;
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h3 style="--num: 1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h3>
<h3 style="--num: 2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h3>
<h3 style="--num: 3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h3>
<h3 style="--num: 42">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h3>
<h3 style="--num: 256">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h3>
```

But this isn't that reliable. The `background-clip: text` property is still under a prefix on some browsers. And you need to manually set the gradient cutoff between the number and the dot, depending in the font.